# How can I make the page list line break when using the acronym part of the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, classicthesis

I am using `glossaries` to keep track of acronyms in my thesis (using commands like `\acrlong`, `\acrshort` and `\acrfull`).

However, in the acronym list towards the end of the thesis, there are no line breaks in the page list where the terms are mentioned.  This causes terms that are mentioned on a lot of places only to have a few of them included until there is no more space on the line.

EDIT;  I tried using the glossaries package in a fresh document to create a MWE, and it worked nicely with linebreaks.  Turns out then, that it is something in the Classicthesis package that prevents this from happening.  It's going to be harder to create Classicthesis MWE, because files are, per default, spread over many directories, etc.  But something is stopping the linebreaks from occurring when the glossary list (acronym, really) is printed, and someone might have a hunch as to why?

EDIT2; After changing the style as the glossaries package was loaded from "long" to "index", linebreaks started occurring.  No idea why, but this actually fixed the problem even if the "long" style was prettier.

EDIT3; I have tried to compile a MWE.  The minimum is to edit a standard Classicthesis setup file, comment out all references to the auxiliary files, and enter the acronyms in the main file itself.  Furthermore, the classicthesis-config.tex file was edited to reflect the loading of the glossaries package.  As I found out, changing the style from "long" to "index" made line breaks happen again.  Otherwise everything is unchanged from a fresh Classicthesis zip file.

Classicthis.tex

```
**************************************************************************************************************
% A Classic Thesis Style
% An Homage to The Elements of Typographic Style
%
% Copyright (C) 2012 Andr\'e Miede http://www.miede.de
%
% If you like the style then I would appreciate a postcard. My address 
% can be found in the file ClassicThesis.pdf. A collection of the 
% postcards I received so far is available online at 
% http://postcards.miede.de
%
% License:
% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
% it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
% the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
% (at your option) any later version.
%
% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
% GNU General Public License for more details.
%
% You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
% along with this program; see the file COPYING.  If not, write to
% the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330,
% Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.
%
% **************************************************************************************************************
% Note:
%    * You must not use "u etc. in strings/commands that will be spaced out (use \"u or real umlauts instead)
%    * New enumeration (small caps): \begin{aenumerate} \end{aenumerate}
%    * For margin notes: \marginpar or \graffito{}
%    * Do not use bold fonts in this style, it is designed around them
%    * Use tables as in the examples
%    * See classicthesis-preamble.sty for useful commands
% **************************************************************************************************************
% To Do:
%                * [high] Check this out: http://www.golatex.de/koma-script-warnung-in-verbindung-mit-listings-package-t2058.html
%    * [medium] mathbb in section-titles/chapter-titles => disappears somehow in headlines!!!
% **************************************************************************************************************
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
                ngerman,american,%
                ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}

%********************************************************************
% Hyphenation
%*******************************************************
%\hyphenation{put special hyphenation here}

% ********************************************************************
% GO!GO!GO! MOVE IT!
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%********************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%*******************************************************
%\include{FrontBackmatter/DirtyTitlepage}
%\include{FrontBackmatter/Titlepage}
%\include{FrontBackmatter/Titleback}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Dedication}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Foreword}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Abstract}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Publication}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Acknowledgments}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Contents}
%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{90}
% use \cleardoublepage here to avoid problems with pdfbookmark
\cleardoublepage
\part{Some Kind of Manual}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter01}
\include{mwe-glossaries}
%\cleardoublepage
%\ctparttext{You can put some informational part preamble text here. 
%Illo principalmente su nos. Non message \emph{occidental} angloromanic
%da. Debitas effortio simplificate sia se, auxiliar summarios da que,
%se avantiate publicationes via. Pan in terra summarios, capital
%interlingua se que. Al via multo esser specimen, campo responder que
%da. Le usate medical addresses pro, europa origine sanctificate nos se.}
%\part{The Showcase}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter02}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage} % <--- just debug stuff, ignore
%\include{Chapters/Chapter03}
%\include{multiToC} % <--- just debug stuff, ignore for your documents
% ********************************************************************
% Backmatter
%*******************************************************
\newacronym{ascii}{ASCII}{American Standard Code for Information Interchange}
\newacronym{upgma}{UPGMA}{Unweighted Pair-Group Method using Arithmetic averages}
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
\acrlong{ascii}
\newpage
\acrlong{upgma}
\newpage
Trying to print list of glossaries


\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\part{Appendix}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter0A}
\printglossaries
%********************************************************************
% Other Stuff in the Back
%*******************************************************
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Bibliography}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Colophon}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Declaration}
% ********************************************************************
% Game Over: Restore, Restart, or Quit?
%*******************************************************
\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

classicthesis-config.tex

```
% ****************************************************************************************************
% classicthesis-config.tex 
% formerly known as loadpackages.sty, classicthesis-ldpkg.sty, and classicthesis-preamble.sty 
% Use it at the beginning of your ClassicThesis.tex, or as a LaTeX Preamble 
% in your ClassicThesis.{tex,lyx} with \input{classicthesis-config}
% ****************************************************************************************************  
% If you like the classicthesis, then I would appreciate a postcard. 
% My address can be found in the file ClassicThesis.pdf. A collection 
% of the postcards I received so far is available online at 
% http://postcards.miede.de
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below 
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,%
                                 pdfspacing,%floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
                                 subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}
% ********************************************************************
% Available options for classicthesis.sty 
% (see ClassicThesis.pdf for more information):
% drafting
% parts nochapters linedheaders
% eulerchapternumbers beramono eulermath pdfspacing minionprospacing
% tocaligned dottedtoc manychapters
% listings floatperchapter subfig
% ********************************************************************

% ********************************************************************
% Triggers for this config
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} % enable backrefs in the bibliography
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{false} % true false
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{A Classic Thesis Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{An Homage to The Elements of Typographic Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{Doktor-Ingenieur (Dr.-Ing.)\xspace}
\newcommand{\myName}{Andr\'e Miede\xspace}
\newcommand{\myProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{Darmstadt\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{August 2012\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 4.1\xspace}

% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.} 
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 3. Loading some handy packages
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ******************************************************************** 
% Packages with options that might require adjustments
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{latin9}{inputenc} % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
 \usepackage{inputenc}

%\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,american}{babel}   % change this to your language(s)
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
 \usepackage{babel}

\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}           % math environments and more by the AMS 
 \usepackage{amsmath}

% ******************************************************************** 
% General useful packages
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
        \usepackage{fontenc}     
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package          
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff 
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
        \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
%\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textssc{#1}} % for MinionPro
%\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}  
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings} 
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,%left,%
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
    %frame=L
} 
% ****************************************************************************************************                     


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. PDFLaTeX, hyperreferences and citation backreferences
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Using PDFLaTeX
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
        \usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
        \usepackage{graphicx} 

% ********************************************************************
% Setup the style of the backrefs from the bibliography
% (translate the options to any language you use)
% ********************************************************************
\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax}%(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{(Cited on page~#1.)}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{(Cited on pages~#1.)}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}}%
{%
                \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
                \usepackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
                   \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
                   \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
                   \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
                   \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% detailed backref
                      \ifcase #1 %
                         \backrefnotcitedstring%
                      \or%
                         \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
                      \else%
                         \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
                      \fi}%
}{\relax}    

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences
% ********************************************************************
\hypersetup{%
    %draft,     % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={\myTitle},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName, \myUni, \myFaculty},%
    pdfsubject={},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}   

% ********************************************************************
% Setup autoreferences
% ********************************************************************
% There are some issues regarding autorefnames
% http://www.ureader.de/msg/136221647.aspx
% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords
% you have to redefine the makros for the 
% language you use, e.g., american, ngerman
% (as chosen when loading babel/AtBeginDocument)
% ********************************************************************
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
       \addto\extrasamerican{%
                                        \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}% 
                                }%
       \addto\extrasngerman{% 
                                        \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
                                        \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%        
                                        \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
                                }%
                        % Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right (thanks to Belinda Vogt for changing the definition)
                        \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%  
    }{\relax}
\makeatother


\usepackage[style=long,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 7. Last calls before the bar closes
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Development Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\listfiles
%\PassOptionsToPackage{l2tabu,orthodox,abort}{nag}
%       \usepackage{nag}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{warning, all}{onlyamsmath}
%       \usepackage{onlyamsmath}

% ********************************************************************
% Last, but not least...
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{classicthesis}
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 8. Further adjustments (experimental)
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Changing the text area
% ********************************************************************
%\linespread{1.05} % a bit more for Palatino
%\areaset[current]{312pt}{761pt} % 686 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head \the\footskip
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%

% ********************************************************************
% Using different fonts
% ********************************************************************
%\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts} % oldstyle notextcomp
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
%\usepackage{hfoldsty} % Computer Modern with osf
%\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{iwona}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % <-- no osf support :-(
%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign} <-- no osf support :-(
% ****************************************************************************************************
```

How can I fix this?  (Other than dropping the page reference some places, that is).

Here is a snapshot of two Acronyms in the list of acronyms.  The vertical line marks the end of the page, where the further mentions of the term are simply truncated:
[image: too long line]

Comment: Please provide a compilable document that shows this feature. At the moment, it's unclear to me

Comment: Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) this is purely guesswork, but are you displaying the page list in a tabular-like environment that doesn't permit line breaks? (Such as the `long4col` style.)

Comment: In my thesis, references are made hundreds of places, and everything works fine, except that on the last page where the acronyms are output, the page number list does not break, and continues into "open space".

Comment: Unless you provide a MWE, you are _very unlikely_ to get any help with this problem, since we do not know what your setup/preamble is like. Why would it be so hard to include a MWE with `classicthesis`? It is included in most of (if not all) TeX distributions after all. What files are you talking about, that are spread all over the place? Also, without a MWE your question might be closed because it is unclear to everyone what you are asking.

Comment: I tried to include the two central files now.  But nothing has really been changed in the code, except adding the glossaries package.  Perhaps there are references to other files there, but this could be enough to get it to compile, with the classicthesis.sty present, of course.   The thing is that the list of page references does not line break with the "long" style.  I'm not sure how to be more specific than that.  Why does not not line break is my question.